# Rails Seed DB From CSV - Trouble With Date Format

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, csv, rake

(Here's my requisite line about being new to ruby/rails and programming in general; first SO question as well)

I have a rake task to seed my MySQL DB from a CSV-

```
...
    CSV.read(uri).each do |row|
      Incident.create(
        :building_address => row[9],
        :agency => row[3],
        :complaint_type => row[6],
        :descriptor => row[5],
        :created => row[1],
        :closed => row[2],
        )
end
```

`:created` and `:closed` are defined as date fields (and are also separate from/unrelated to the rails created_at and updated_at fields), but I'm assuming CSV files recognize only strings.

When I run this task, day and month get switched around. So `1/12/2010 12:00:00 AM` in the CSV (which for the CSV and myself in the US means January 12) ends up being parsed as 2010-12-1, and any day past 12 returns null, so `1/20/2010 12:00:00 AM` results in a null entry in my DB.

I added

```
date:
    formats:
        default: "%m/%d/%Y"
```

to my en.yml, but that seems to only affect the display of a date, and has no effect on the creation of objects through my rake task. After searching around SO and other resources I tried

```
:created => row[1].strftime,
```

and

```
:created => row[1].strptime,
```

but got `undefined method strptime/strftime for "Created Date":String` (Created Date being the name of the column in the CSV).

So I also tried

```
:created => row[1].to_date
```

to change the (presumably) "date" string in the CSV to a date, but get an error `undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass`

Changing the date field in the CSV seems like a nonstarter as there are 1 million+ records.

How can I edit this rake task to properly seed my db from this CSV? Or should I change :created from a date to string and manipulate it in the application logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`DateTime.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) to convert your strings to DateTime instances:

```
:created => DateTime.strptime(row[1], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'),
:closed  => DateTime.strptime(row[2], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

The `strptime` class method will let you specify exactly the format you're using so that none of the software has to guess. I'd recommend that you stick to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO8601) date and time formats for internal use in the future, leave the ambiguous formats for human consumption.

Comment: Tried this and a few variations last night, but keep getting an `invalid date` error. I thought maybe because `:created` and `:closed` were Date class instead of DateTime, but changing didn't help. Will keep trying tonight while also reading up more on the ruby docs you linked to.

Comment: @sbauch: What type are the `:created` and `:closed` columns? Are they `date`, `datetime`, or `timestamp`? If they're dates then try `Date.strptime(row[1], '%m/%d/%Y')` and `Date.strptime(row[2], '%m/%d/%Y')` to ignore the time of day part.

Comment: I tried it with both. Right now I have both columns as `date` and am able to use `Date.strptime('12/15/2010 12:00 AM', '%m/%d/%Y')` (having copied that date directly from my csv) in my console fine. But still getting the `invalid date` error on the rake task.

Comment: @sbauch: Which one is complaining about an "invalid date", `Date` or `Incident`?

Comment: Looks like my CSV header was gumming this up. Thanks for the help! 
edit- Though I think I figured this out, how would one tell? I was getting `invalid date
/Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb:1022:in new_by_frags'`

Comment: @sbauch: Cool. You `Date.strptime` raises an ArgumentError exception when it can't parse the string; so you could add a `rescue ArgumentError => e` and note what's in `e`.